# C++ List of objects are only copies

Tags: c++, stl

I find myself needing to keep two lists of objects for performance reasons (speed over memory).

I'm using object pointers such as

```
std::list<MyClass*> m_list1;
std::list<MyClass*> m_list2;
```

I add objects to the list by

```
MyClass* myObject = new MyClass();
m_list1.push_back(myObject);
m_list2.push_back(myObject);
```

The problem I'm facing is that changes I make to `m_list1` are not affecting `m_list2`, so clearly they are copies and not the real deal.

What is the correct way to store these so they won't be copies? Not using pointers isn't an option as these will all be allocated on the heap.

Comment: *changes I make to m_list1 are not affecting m_list2* Are you saying that you delete/insert an item in `m_list1` but `m_list2` doesn't have the update? That's to be expected. As for the pointers themselves, they are pointing to the same heap object, so changes to an **instance** in one list will be reflected in the other. Could you clarify your confusion?

Comment: Take a look at [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and see if that doesn't suit your purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Std containers copy the values passed in, but since you passed in pointers, it is the pointers that are copied. Therefore they are still pointing to the same object. The problem must be somewhere else. Perhaps you could post the specific code that you think is exhibiting this behavior?

Comment: After your post I double checked my code and forgot that I delete and add a new object to one of the lists which would mess up the two lists. Silly mistake >_>